# Three sides circular textinputfield with one side rectangle in flutter

Tags: flutter, textinput

I need to add a text field which has 3 sides circular shape and one top right side with normal rectangular side.
I am trying to do that with OutlineInputBorder which gives me borders.
However I need to achieve this design.

Since I dont have enough reputations, I am not allowed to add images.
It will helpful if someone help me out.

```
    new Theme(
          data: new ThemeData(
            primaryColor: Colors.blue,
          ),
          child: TextFormField(
            style: new TextStyle(
              color: Color(0xff651515),
            ),
            autofocus: false,
            obscureText: false,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,

            decoration: InputDecoration(
              filled: true,
              border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))
              ),
              fillColor: Colors.black12,
              labelText: TextDisplayConstants.EMAIL,
              labelStyle: TextStyle(
                color: Color(0xffa4a4a4),
                fontSize: 14,
              ),
            ),[enter image description here][1]
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a try with this:

**Demo:**

[image: Demo border]

**Example code:**

```
OutlineInputBorder(
           borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(10),
                topRight: Radius.circular(0)),
          )
```

Comment: And also if someone needs to use color for border, u can use like-----                                                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent).

Answer (score 2):

Just Replace your border in Textformfield code like,

```
border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(20),
                      bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                      bottomRight: Radius.circular(0),
                    ),
                  ),
```

Add the Radius.circular(0) on the side which you want rectangle border like, **bottomRight: Radius.circular(0)**

Answer (score 0):

```
    border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                           bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                           topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                           topRight: Radius.circular(20)
                                                   )
                                  ),
```

TextFormField

```
TextFormField(
        style: new TextStyle(
          color: Color(0xff651515),
        ),
        autofocus: false,
        obscureText: false,
        keyboardType: TextInputType.text,

        decoration: InputDecoration(
          filled: true,
          border: new OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20),topLeft: Radius.circular(20),topRight: Radius.circular(20))
          ),
          fillColor: Colors.black12,

          labelStyle: TextStyle(
            color: Color(0xffa4a4a4),
            fontSize: 14,
          ),
        )
      ),
```